# Cross cluster communication in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have two kubernetes clusters running inside **AWS EKS**. How can I connect them both so that both can communicate and share data ?

On one cluster only stateless applications are running while on another stateful like **Redis DB**, **RabbitMQ** etc.

Which will be the easiest way to setup communication ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a specific cluster to run DBs and other private stateful workloads, then ensure that your worker nodes for that EKS cluster are private.

Next step would be to create service resource to expose your Redis DB with an internal endpoint. You can achieve it by specifying following:

```
annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

With the above you are going to have entire cluster and stateful workloads exposed using internal endpoints. Once this is done, you have two options to connect your VPCs.

1. VPC peering to allow one cluster to connect with the other.
2. Transit Gateway which two VPCs will use to communicate privately.

Answer (score 0):

I will be following the suggested approach by @marcincuber to use internal load balancer.

However, I also got one another workaround exposing the **Redis, RabbitMQ** service type as `LoadBalancer`.

Since my both cluster in the same VPC there is no need of VPC peering or any gateway setup, I am thinking to restrict the traffic via using Kubernetes default service `loadBalancerSourceRanges`.

Comment: This is a public way of exposing your private services. I am not a big fan of doing it this way. But also possible, assuming your worker nodes are running in private subsets and you are routing out through Nat gateway with elastic ip attached. This is applicable to cluster that communicates with redis etc. Naturally, you will be whitelisting that elastic ip on your external load balancer.

Comment: @marcincuber you are absolutely right i do agree with your point but in some case, clusters are already configured & not having proper access to touch worker nodes. however, having full access to Kubernetes cluster but not having access of AWS console.