# EKS cross cluster internal DNS lookup

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

We have 2 EKS clusters, cluster#1 for applications and cluster#2 for observability.

If we are to avoid routing through public internet but limited to VPC peering between the EKS cluster, how can pods from one cluster lookup the internal name of pods `{service name}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local` from another cluster?

Comment: Hello, have you seen Istio multicluster setup on it's homepage? https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/ . It's describing setup similar to one you would like to achieve.

Comment: Inter-cluster trust and gateway looks like good fit, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments:

> Hello, have you seen Istio multicluster setup on it's homepage? https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/
> . It's describing setup similar to one you would like to achieve.

#### Istio

One of the solutions would be to use the setup mentioned in the official docs of `Istio`:

- *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Setup: Install: Multicluster](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/)*

Above documentation describes installation and configuration of Istio mesh across multiple clusters. There are multiple deployment models to choose from which can be found here:

- *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Ops: Deployment: Deployment models](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/deployment-models/)*

You will need to choose the option that suits you needs the most.

---

#### `EKS` App Mesh

You can also take a look on solution specific to `EKS` which is `App Mesh`:

- *[Aws.amazon.com: Blog: Containers: Getting started with App Mesh and EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/getting-started-with-app-mesh-and-eks/)*

More specific guide that is recognizing the need for more than 1 cluster is described here (with Cloud Map):

- *[Aws.amazon.com: Blogs: Containers: Cross amazon EKS cluster App Mesh using AWS Cloud Map](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/cross-amazon-eks-cluster-app-mesh-using-aws-cloud-map/)*

---

#### Additional resources

- *[Docs.aws.amazon.com: Quickstart: Architecture: Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/amazon-eks/)*
- *[Istio.io](https://istio.io/)*

I also found this Stackoverflow question which is taking a different approach to the question asked (using **internal** `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`):

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Cross cluster communication in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60038177/cross-cluster-communication-in-kubernetes)*